# How long must I wait after buying a property to rent it out?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, real-estate, rental-property, first-time-home-buyer

I bought a place as a first time buyer without mortgage.  Consequently I paid a 3% stamp duty. Due to certain circumstances, I will have to rent it out. I would like to know how long before I could rent it out. Would it have money consequences as I only paid the 3% duty?

Comment: I'm confused: how do you get a 3% rate if it isn't a second home?

Comment: `Would it have money consequences as I only paid the 3% duty` Why would you think so ? Have you availed of any government scheme ?

Comment: Hello

It is not a second home, it was the first property I bought. I'll have to live with with one of my relatives in need of care. 
many thanks

Comment: No I did not . But, I know that under law if you are not first buyer, the stamp duty would have been 5%. And I really do not want to breach any Inland Revenue regulations.